# How to replace an HTML element's value with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

After searching for some text blobs in an html file liket this:

```
s="the Quick brown fox..."
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('file.html'), 'html.parser')
matches = soup.find_all(lambda x: x.text == s)
for match in matches:
    print(match.parent)
```

```
<div class="container-box"><div class="title-box">label</div><p span="" style="font-:normal">the Quick brown fox...</p></div>
```

How can I replace in the html file only the matched entry's `label` string? For example, for the above finded element, I would like to replace `label` with `tomatoes`?

```
<div class="container-box"><div class="title-box">tomatoes</div><p span="" style="font-:normal">the Quick brown fox...</p></div>
```

So far I tried this:

In:

```
matches = soup.find_all(lambda x: x.text == s)
for match in matches:
    target = match.parent.find("div", {"class": "title-box"})
    print(target.replace_with("tomatoes"))
```

Out:

```
<div class="title-box">label</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for match in matches:
    #target = match.parent.find('div')

    #EDIT
    target = match.parent.select_one('div.title-box')
    target.replace_with("tomatoes")
soup
```

Output:

```
<html><body><div class="container-box">tomatoes<p span="" style="font-:normal">the Quick brown fox...</p></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is that I have several nested divs. If I try this solution I will replace other things that I must not touch

Comment: I tried this: `match.parent.find("div", {"class": "title-box"}).replace_with("tomatoes")`

Comment: @aywoki I can only work with what you posted in the question. I have no idea what the "real" html looks like....

Comment: The problem is that it is a large file and I am only interested in the part that matches that string

Comment: Please check my update, maybe that can help

Comment: @aywoki See the EDIT line in the question and check against your actual html.

Comment: Thanks for your time